# XQuery: removing newline/return character from end of a string stored in a variable in query

Tags: xquery, flwor, functx

How do I remove a new-line/return from the end of a variable? I tried `functx:substring-before-last` to try and remove the new line (denoting it as `\r`, `\n` and also as `\r\n`) but still when I output that variable's value, the newline is still there in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use [`fn:normalize-space($arg as xs:string?)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-space) to remove all additional whitespace:

> Summary: Returns the value of `$arg` with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of one or more than one whitespace character with a single space, `#x20`.

Or you can just use [`fn:replace(..)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) and a regular expression:

```
fn:replace($string, '(\r?\n|\r)$', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

CR and NL can be specified as `&#13;` and `&#10;`. The following regular expression will remove all trailing newlines from your input string:

```
replace($string, '(&#xd;?&#xa;)*$', '')
```

If you want to normalize all whitespaces of a string, `normalize-string` is another, more readable option:

```
normalize-space($string)
```

Comment: Leo is right; I forgot that you can simply use \r\n within regular expressions.

Comment: I tried your code-- this is the error I got(I am using Saxon processor in a java app to process Xquery commands) -- Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: The regular expression in replace() must not be one that matches a zero-length string
 at net.sf.saxon.functions.Replace.maybePrecompile(Replace.java:52)....